# at command throws 'cannot set egid: Operation not permitted error'

Tags: at-job

I'm trying to execute a command using the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php xxx.php | at now + 10 minutes
```

However, terminal throws this error:

```
cannot set egid: Operation not permitted error
```

I tried adding the user to /etc/at.allow but that doesn't help. I also removed /etc/at.deny, but that also didn't help. Any ideas what is up? How can I give permission to the user to utilize the at command?

Comment: Make sure `/usr/bin/at` has the `set-uid` mode set. I think this happens if it's not set. See http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lnx_eng_01-linux_capabilities-v2.1.3-compact-syn_0.pdf

Comment: @Barmar How would I check and how would I change it if it doesn't have it?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/at` shows the permission modes. `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/at` will add setuid.

Comment: This is what `ls -l /usr/bin/at` shows: `-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 54336`

Comment: OK. Can't you see that it doesn't have the set-uid flag? You're administering a Unix system, you should know how to read permissions.

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't be asking o_O In either case, I ran `chmod u+s /usr/bin/at` and now I get `You do not have permission to use at.`

Comment: That means you're not in `at.allow`.

Comment: Read `man at.allow` to learn how to use the `at.allow` and `at.deny` files properly.

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from the webserver. In that case, remember that the username that has to be in `at.allow` is the webserver user (e.g. `www-data`), not your own username.

Comment: You are awesome. It works. Can you put this as an answer so I give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions on `/usr/bin/at` are incorrect, it needs to be `setuid` to root:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/at
```